# How can I fix EOF problem in the second script (below the dotted line)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, eof

This program essentially encodes and decodes a message and code respectively. I only did the decoding part so far. However I keep getting an EOF error even though I made sure to end parentheses, checked my syntax and kept tampering with it. Unfortunately no luck. Anyone know why this error keeps popping up? I would greatly appreciate it. Also I copied both files that i'm using.

```
from LetterCodeLogic import LCL

def main():
    print("Welcome to the LetterCode program")

choice = getChoice()
while choice !=0:
    if choice == 1:
        #Encode logic...
        print()
    elif choice == 2:
        #Decode logic...
        msg = input("Enter your numbers to decode (separate with commas): ")
        #send msg to Decode function in LCL class (LetterCodeLogic.py file)
        result = LCL.Decode(msg)
        print("Your decoded message is: \n" + result)
    else:
        print("Unknown process...")
    print()
    choice = getChoice()
print("Thanks for using the Letter Code program")

def getChoice():
    c = int(input("Choice? (1=Encode, 2=Decode, 0=Quit): "))
    return c

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

---

```
class LCL:
"""Encode/Decode Functions"""

@staticmethod
def Decode(msg):
    #separate numbers from msg string (e.g., "1,2,3")
    nums = msg.split(",")   #produces list of separate items
    result = ""
    for x in nums:
        try:
            n = int(x.strip())  #remove leading/trailing spaces...
            if n == 0:
                c = " "
            elif n < 0 or n > 26:
                c = "?"
            else:
                #ASCII scheme has A=65, B=66, etc.
                c = chr(n+64)
        except ValueError:
            c = "?"
            
        result += c     #same as: result = result + c
        
    return result


@staticmethod
def Encode(msg):
```

Comment: Which file causes the problem? There is an unfinished function in the first file,  that one is definitely illegal.

Comment: please elaborate on what the error is that you are getting, EOF is short for End Of File which is related to reading files which you aren't doing. Which line throws the error? also please format code correctly, paste the code into SO then highlight it and click the `{}` button to correctly format it, as of now it looks like there are indentation inconsistencies.

Comment: _I keep getting an EOF error_ Telling us about the error isn't very helpful.  SHOW us the error.

Comment: Oh I'm sorry. The error is in file 2 (bottom one). The error specifically says "unexpected EOF while parsing". It throws it on the very last line of the second file.

Answer (score 0):

the "@staticmethod" and "def Encode()" function was empty and that was the end of line parsing error. When I was coding this and ran it, it ran with no problems. So I removed it for the time being.